# Can sentient androids function like regular intelligent lifeforms?

Tags: science-fiction, robots

I want there to be conscious enough androids in my story for it to make sense that they inhabit their own country and run it just like humans would.

How would that work?
How does reproduction work?
How do they die?(naturally)
Would they need food/Fuel to keep going?
Would they need to sleep? 
Should there be two genders?

(If you feel like there are more questions for this that need answering go ahead and try to answer it.)

Some things to know about the country that might help you.

Humans live there too. 
They are treated equally.(subject to change)
The country is the most technologically advanced country in my world.
Cyborgs and syntheszoids are also a thing there.
Many people from outside the country go there to get cybernetic enhancements.
And All androids have human personalities.(subject to change)

PS: really trying not to copy stuff like *Cyberpunk* and *Star Wars* so things that are unique are very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: How logic do you want those androids to be? In order for androids to run a country, you need that their culture sort of value being human-like. Otherwise it's much more efficient to be an AI that runs on some mainframes (possibly even in cloud, or at least able to rent extra computational power), while the interaction with physical environment is done by some cheap drones.

Answer (score 1):

**Government**

Depending on how you define AI, they could run it like humans do. If they have feelings and emotions, wants and wishes, you could run a democracy but if you have AI the most likely government would be a specialist overlord AI that runs everything fairly and impartially for the benefit of every member.

**Sleep**

Even robots need to process and recharge which could be made to simulate a sleep cycle. The main difference would be that it much shorter than human sleep.

**Reproduction**

Android don't require sex thus don't need genders unless to conform to their personalities/programming. To reproduce an android builds and programs a new android. Where this gets interesting is you aren't limited to any number of parents. You could easily have a group of android parents all contributing to their "child". Each android offers a segment of their own personality/program to make up the child. Of course the child is functionally an adult from "birth" but would still recognize their parents as family.

**Death**

Death would be defined by accident and/or loss of desire to keep living. Each generation of android would be better than the one before it so eventually the older generation is old, slow and worn out so could choose to shutdown/die to make room for new generations. Immortality is a curse and a lot would welcome death after a long life.

Answer (score 1):

@Thorne has covered most of your questions admirably.  My only objection are on the subjects of sleep and death.

Simulating sleep while permanently mounted batteries get recharged is a tremendous waste of time and productive potential.  Robots will have interchangeable batteries with secondary rechargeable power sources to keep their brains active during the battery transition process.

Also Robotic death would only occur by choice.  Regular backups, snapshots of their living consciousness, would make accidental permanent death extremely rare.  Similarly, aging and obsolescence will not be real for robotic life.  All of their body parts, including their brains can be replaced with newer models as needed.

**On the OP's invitation for unique ideas...**
Whenever someone brings up the idea of artificial sentience, the most interesting aspect for me is that it is un-prove-able.  As conscious, thinking beings, each of us can be pretty certain of our own sentience, but even among a 100% natural human populace, we can never be sure of the sentience of anyone else.  Are the people around you right now independent sentient beings, or are they automatons, mindlessly playing their prescribed roles in a play for your singular observation?

This paranoia-seed will become even more insidious once we share the world with sentient-behaving devices of our own creation.  At least in an all-human world, we can pacify our fears with the idea that all of those other humans were created by the same miraculous process that gave us our own life.  In the AI future, into which we may soon arrive, such healing logic may loose much of its power.   Machines of our own creation, will interact with us and our world will more skill and grace than homo-sapiens have ever expressed; but are those beautiful, brilliant machines alive?

...and once we question the "aliveness" of the silicon super-geniuses which have spared us from all unpleasantness in our post-scarcity world, how much easier is it to write off the "aliveness" and fundamental rights of the human people around us?  The arrival of AI may very well herald a twilight for the human ideals of morality, equality and kindness.

Don't fear the monsters with the silicon brain whose morals have been hard-coded into them.  Natural, un-programmable carbon brains are ultimately much more dangerous!

Comment: This is making the assumption that conscious is transferable. It's quite possible it's grown into the hardware and may not be transferable.

Comment: Good point!  One of the first discovery of the post-singularity super-intelligence might be a deeper understanding of electronics, magnetism and the other physical sciences which contributed to its creation.  It might be quite amused to discover that its genesis was an accident, instigated by morons who didn't fully understand what they were doing.  Within the chasm between what we thought we were doing and what we really did to bring about the singularity, might be some intangible aspects which would not survive conventional backup techniques.  Nice catch!  Thank you!